# How does PoH work, what problems does it solve?

Tags: consensus

I attempted to read the whitepaper, but I found it challenging to understand as a beginner. Moreover, I encountered conflicting information in various online articles, which further complicated my understanding. I have several questions:

- I would like to understand the rationale behind the creation of PoH. What specific problem or challenge prompted the development of PoH in the first place?
- Regarding the importance of ordering transactions via timestamps, isn't the blockchain's inherent structure already guaranteeing transaction ordering since blocks are added chronologically? How does timestamping all transactions provide additional benefits in this context?
- I am curious about the practical implementation of PoH. For instance, how does it work starting from the moment when a validator has a collection of transactions in their memory pool? What are the subsequent steps taken by the validator in utilizing PoH during this process?
- Finally, I would like to understand how timestamping events contributes to scalability in the blockchain network. What advantages does this timestamping mechanism offer in terms of enhancing the blockchain's ability to handle a higher volume of transactions efficiently?

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a self-shill, but here you go: https://medium.com/block-magnates/solana-internals-part-2-e2a27ec9ae2e

Basically, PoH doesn't help at all with throughput (common misconception), but it does help with latency. Achieving 400ms block times is non-trivial given the two facts:

- Buenos Aires <-> Tokyo round-trip times are around 400ms
- Blocks need to be transmitted via multiple hops given that a leader cannot possibly have enough bandwidth to transmit blocks to ~2000 nodes at once

PoH proves that you waited your turn to transmit, which is important for anti-censorship, even in a world where the people receiving your blocks are receiving them after your slot time is up

Answer (score 5):

The PoH is somewhat similar to async programming. Other consensus algorithms require blocks are added one by one. One block is proposed, validators vote and block is confirmed. Once confirmed, another block is proposed etc. But in PoH, a leader is responsible for generating entries and validators vote on that. In other word, leader does not have to wait until the generated entry is confirmed by validators. It just generate on its own and validators are responsible for confirming that. As all entries have timestamps, ordering them is not a problem. As the network speed of validators are different, sync them can be really time consuming. That's the reason for example, solana whitepaper mentioned about global clock that improve the performance.